# closed source version control software

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, bazaar, plasticscm

Why would some people purchase closed source version control software (such as Code co-op and plastic SCM) while there are many open source software like git, Mercurial and Bazaar? Does closed source vcs have some benefits that open source vcs doesn't?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because PlasticSCM is simply better than any others out there.  Also it is free for up to 15 users.  Works with Git Repos and makes visualization of branching so much better.  I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

As the free vcs's become more mature there is very little reason (well, none really) to buy a closed source vcs.

Some companies will do this on policy, or for tight integration with an entire ALM suite (team foundation or equiv). Some will buy, so that they have some level of influence over the tool, big customers can have some clout.